# Unable to pass String to onClick Function :Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have anchor tag and on click of it I am trying to pass parameters into the function but I am getting the error uncaught ReferenceError: testbody is not defined.

```
<a onClick="editComment(<%= comment.body%>)">Edit Comment</a>
```

testbody is the value stores in db and its of type text. Strangely when I pass something which is integer then no error is shown.

Answer (score 3):

If I remember you need to add quote marks like so around the erb.

```
<a onClick="editComment('<%= comment.body%>')">Edit Comment</a>
```

Comment: be sure to use `escape_javascript` in case `comment.body` contains single or double quotes.